# How can I get the response headers?

Tags: php, header

I'm currently connecting to a remote host in PHP CLI and sending some headers. My script then waits for the response. I can have it all print out, but then it returns the HTML. I only want the headers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for receiving a HTTP response is basically the same as for sending a request: headers and body are separated with two CRLF (`\r\n\r\n`).

```
$parts = explode("\r\n\r\n", $http_response);
$headers = array_shift($parts);
$body = implode("\r\n\r\n", $parts);
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use [get_headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)?

Comment: Do you mean browsing the response text to extract headers? As "[He] only wants the headers" I think this function is the best way? Or don't I all understand? ^^

Comment: The OP didnt specify how s/he connects to the remote server. I agree `get_headers` is the easiest way to do it. It does a HEAD request and returns the headers in an array. That's easy and cake, but if for some reason the OP cannot use this method, doing a HEAD request manually (e.g. with cURL or HTTP extension) instead of doing a full GET is the smarter way, because it wont return any response body then.

Comment: @MatTheCat, how would we get the response headers for the current HTTP response?

Answer (score 0):

If you really only need the headers use [`get_headers`](http://php.net/get_headers), if you need both content and headers use a normal filesystem function and find the headers in [`$http_response_header`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php).