# Get response headers in PHP from vhost configuration

Tags: php, apache, http

I have a vhost configuration that has a directive to add a response header to every request, like this:

`Header append X-MyHeader "Info Stuff in here"`

If I run `phpinfo()` on this server, I see this header contained in the apache2handler section under the headline *HTTP Headers Information* as *HTTP Response Headers*. PHP seems to be able to access this info somehow.

I tried `headers_list()` and `apache_response_headers()` to get this information for my script, but it is missing.

A Google search did not come up with a solution, it seems like this to be a rare case. One other question here on SO got the answer to really query the server again and look at the headers, but I won't do this because I need the info on every request I serve - subrequests seem to be too much of a performance penalty.

How does `phpinfo()` know the values?

Update1: PHP does not show the value inside any of the superglobals like `$_SERVER`, `$_ENV` etc. The only place I see it on the phpinfo page is in the above mentioned section. Otherwise this would be a no-brainer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but make sure it's higher in the file than anything else that prints or you will get an error.

```
<?php
foreach($_SERVER as $h=>$v)
 if(preg_match('/HTTP_(.+)/',$h,$hp))
   echo "<li>$h = $v</li>\n";
?>
```

Edit:
Do you have FastCGI enabled?

Try this link: [$_SERVER headers are missing in PHP but present in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141566/server-headers-are-missing-in-php-but-present-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for your help attempt, but this seems completely wrong. The info is not contained in $_SERVER (see my update). And I do not understand why your code first `echo`s, and then tries to set a header - this will fail for sure.

Comment: yeah, that's a typo. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Ok, this clears it up. You are talking about the REQUEST headers from the browser. I am searching for the RESPONSE headers that my server is about to send, but which are not set by PHP, but by the apache config. My PHP runs as apache module.

Comment: Lol. Ok.  I was scratching my head for a second. Have you analyzed your code with something like firebug / google developer tools?  It might help you pin point the problem.

Comment: I know exactly where my problem is: How can I ask PHP to give me the info that PHP displays on the `phpinfo()` page. The header I want to know contains a machine configuration info I want to know, which additionally is sent out as a header to help pinpoint problems with the load balancer. I try to avoid reconfiguring the apache vhost, because that would be the other solution, but takes time.

Comment: I googled to try and find the phpinfo() source code.  The closes I got was downloading the binary for the language.  Maybe this post helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205747/how-can-i-get-the-response-headers